# Chain-Model Getting all objects for template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

models.py

```
class Sirket(models.Model):
    isim = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.isim}"

class Proje(models.Model):
    ad = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    total = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=0)
    kalan = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20,decimal_places=0)
    tarih = models.DateField()
    firma = models.ForeignKey(Sirket, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ad}"

class Santiye(models.Model):
    isim = models.CharField(max_length=20)
    kasa = models.DecimalField(max_digits=20, decimal_places=0, default=0)
    araclar = models.ManyToManyField(Arac)
    baglanti = models.ForeignKey(Proje, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.isim}"
    
class Personel(models.Model):
    ad = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cinsiyet = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    yas = models.DecimalField(max_digits=4, decimal_places=0)
    baslamaTarih = models.DateField()
    resim = models.FileField(default="static/images/avatar.jpg")
    birim = models.ForeignKey(Santiye, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    def __str__(self):
        return f"{self.ad}"
```

views.py

```
def firma(request):
    sirket = Sirket.objects.all().prefetch_related('proje_set').order_by('id')
    # i have multiple classes with connect each other.
    # like Proje class connected to Sirket class with many-to-one relationship.
    # It goes like : Sirket -> Proje -> Santiye -> Personel 
    # I'm trying to access the Personel.ad objects that are linked to the Sirket.
```

template

```
<div class="container">

    <div class="row">
    
        {% for sirket in sirket %}
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="card-body">
                                <p class="card-text"><b>Çalışan Personeller:</b></p>
                                    <p>{% for personel in santiye.personel_set.all %}
                                        <li>{{personel.ad}}</li>
                                    {% endfor %}</p> 

                                 **<!-- I try to list santiye personels like above -->  **    

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>

        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

I have multiple classes with connect each other.
Like Proje class connected to Sirket class with many-to-one relationship.
It goes like : Sirket -> Proje -> Santiye -> Personel.
I'm trying to access the Personel.ad objects that are linked to the Sirket.

I tried something like this:

`sirket = Sirket.objects.all().prefetch_related('proje__santiye__personel_set').order_by('id')`

But not working of course, and gives the following error:

> AttributeError at /products/firma
> Cannot find 'proje' on Sirket object, 'proje__santiye__personel_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()

Is there any way to make this work with view or in template?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message suggests that there is no attribute named `'proje'` on the `sirket` object. This is because you have defined the foreign key relation on the `Proje` model, not on the `Sirket` model.

So use the following view:

```py
def firma(request):
    sirket = Sirket.objects.all().prefetch_related('proje_set__santiye_set__personel_set').order_by('id')
    return render(request, "firma.html", {"sirket": sirket})
```

Here, we are prefetching the related objects from `Proje` to `Personel` using the `"__"` syntax to traverse through the foreign key relations.

Then use in the template as:

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        {% for s in sirket %}
            <div class="card mb-3">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-3">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-9">
                        <div class="card-body">
                            <p class="card-text"><b>{{s.isim}}:</b></p>
                            {% for p in s.proje_set.all %}
                                <p class="card-text"><b>{{p.ad}}:</b></p>
                                {% for san in p.santiye_set.all %}
                                    <p class="card-text"><b>{{san.isim}}:</b></p>
                                    {% for per in san.personel_set.all %}
                                        <li>{{per.ad}}</li>
                                    {% endfor %}
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit complex to debug without mirroring the same project on my machine. But here is a possible solution you can try.

In your view, you can use a prefetch-related method to fetch all related objects to the Sirket model.

```
sirket = Sirket.objects.all().prefetch_related(
    'proje_set__santiye_set__personel_set'
).order_by('id')
```

This should allow you to access the related Personel objects from the Sirket object in your template.

```
{% for sirket in sirket %}
    <div class="card mb-3">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9">
                <div class="card-body">
                    <p class="card-text"><b>Çalışan Personeller:</b></p>
                    <p>
                        {% for proje in sirket.proje_set.all %}
                            {% for santiye in proje.santiye_set.all %}
                                {% for personel in santiye.personel_set.all %}
                                    <li>{{personel.ad}}</li>
                                {% endfor %}
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
                    </p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: The problem is that that there is no attribute named `'proje'` on the sirket object. This is because of  defining the foreign key relation on the `Proje` model, not on the `Sirket` model.